# Azure Devops-is there a way to complete a PR from a release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

I've got a Azure Devops project that's deploying to an app service that has a workflow that looks like this:

1. On PR creation, build gets triggered.
2. Build kicks off a CD pipeline to deploy app service to a staging slot
3. Stage 2 of the CD pipeline is swap staging and prod. This requires an approval
4. PR Still needs to get completed manually

The reason I wanted to build it this way was so that anyone pushing changes to the repo could validate them in the staging slot in the live environment before they went into prod.  The flow seems to work, except that there are two things to do at the end of a change.  The approver must approve the swap to prod task in the pipeline, and the associated PR must be completed.  I've found cases where the PR never gets completed, which means that you end up with unmerged changes.

Is there a way that I can have the release pipeline (which is triggered off a PR build) complete the associated PR as part of a release stage?  I'd like to make sure that what gets merged into the main branch is the current code, so I'd rather not change it to trigger on PR completion because at that point things are already merged, and a breaking change would have to be undone.  The other way I figure I could handle it would be to:

1. On PR Creation, trigger a validation build, and a release pipeline to deploy to the dev slot.
2. On PR completion, trigger a release pipeline to deploy the PR build to prod.

This would change the approval flow a little, but might be better at making sure that the PR gets completed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up coming up with a different flow for this.  What I got working was:

- Create PR for feature branch
- PR creates build
- Staging release pipeline triggers off PR, and deploys to a staging slot
- Changes can be validated in staging
- PR completion merges to main branch
- Merge to main triggers a CI build pipeline
- CI build triggers a release pipeline that goes to the prod slot

This means that the PR must be completed in order to release to prod.  It does mean that the build that goes into prod isn't necessarily the same one that's in staging, but it's built from the same code, so that should be identical.